# What's the best way to ask if an issue has been resolved / things have changed over time

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I was recently wondering about how to validate HTML5 with `og:` meta information.

Research led me **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501189/opengraph-validation-for-html5)**.

Since things change so quick nowadays (already talking like my grandpa) - especially with HTML5 - and this question is already 8 months old (although some of the answers are younger but unfortunately rather worthless) I was wondering what would be the best way to bump this topic:

- ask a completely new question and risk being closed for exact duplicate
- ask a completely new question referring to the old one
- edit the old question to bump it

The question in question (yes!!) might not be the best fitting example, but I have been wondering a couple of times by now how to deal with such a situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be adding a bounty to the question, and explaining in the bounty notice what you are looking for. A bounty will bump the question, and attract widespread attention. Combined with Oded's approach (adding a comment to the best answer), this may be the best way to go.

Comment: I always forget that there can be bounties on answered questions. Sounds like a plan to me.

Comment: But most users don't see question having accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Post a *comment* on the accepted answer (or the one you think is the best/most informed/comprehensive) to ask if the answer is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask another question. And link that question to your question. And leave comment in old question as your question link. So it will help other users that are having the same problem - this way changes will be understandable.